# How to use PrimeNg component in angular2 application?

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to use prime-ng component in my angular2 application but still going confuse how to add in application. Please give a working example of application with prime ng.

Comment: Have you followed the full setup?http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

Answer (score 0):

You have to install primeng and primeicons.

```
npm i primeng primeicons -s
```

Then you have to import the styles in the angular.json. Choose a Theme under ../primeng/ressources/themes/YOUR_CHOOSEN_THEM

```
  "styles": [
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
        ],
```

Now you can import the Modules you need from primeng.